# Export Data From Raspberry Pi to mysql database on a PC via wifi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am new to raspberry pi, and mysql servers, I am hoping I could get some insight on a problem which has occurred. This is a part of a project which is due in a few weeks, and was hoping to have a solution soon.

I am attempting to send data, via wifi, from my raspberry pi to a mysql database located on a PC. The raspberry pi and the mysql database are on the same local wifi network.

On the raspberry pi side, I have used the commands:

"sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector"  and
"sudo apt-get install -f" to install the mysql connector.

my code is as follows:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",             #localhost=ip address of PC
  user="user",
  passwd="1111",
  database="location",
  port="80"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO location (latitude, longitude) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("26.111111", "-80.44444444")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

But the following error occurred: 
self.sock.connect(sockaddr) ConnectionRefusedError:[Errno 111] Connection refused

I'd like to know, are there any other procedures that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to `localhost` instead of your PC, where I suspect your MySQL must be running.

Comment: Correct, I am running MySQL from my PC. What do I replace "localhost" with? Thank you for your response.

Comment: The IP address of your PC.

Comment: I've added "port=80". As 80 is the default port of the mysql database.

Comment: I have replaced "localhost" with my ip4 address. Now I am getting the error mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query. I suspect the issue may now be on the PC's/server's end, but I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I checked to see what apache is listening to in the httpd.conf. It says          
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80                                                                                                            So it appears to be listening to all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

even though the httpd.conf file located on the PC says "Listen 0.0.0.0:80 Listen [::0]:80",

the port in the code should be 3306, instead of 80.